# how to set proper inbound rules to connect Julia to RDS MySQL db

Tags: amazon-web-services, julia

these fields are correctly set, and should be connecting me to the RDS database on aws.

```
con = DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection,
                            "database-1.cgeimvvh4qwz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
                            "admin", "Baya2022", db="database-1")
```

Im wondering if it has something to do with the security group? i think i need to set it to my local ip address, but im not sure how.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details. What errors do you get? What are your current sg rules? Can you connect to the rds anyother way to confirm that it works and the issue is only with Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to AWS RDS you need to:

1. Enable public RDS access in AWS Management Console

   [image]
2. Properly configure Security Group (I use here an unrestricted public access which is something not recommended)
   [image]

Note that

- both steps are required
- in a production environment you would rather use an SSH tunnel - publishing a public RDS endpoint is considered a security hole

Once you are done note that you have used `database-1` which is the default DB Identifier in AWS. However - this is something totally different than the database name! Hence you need to create a database named database-1 first.

Or for testing you can use the system `mysql` database which always gets created such as:

```
julia> con = DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection,
                                   "database-1.cez1pkekt7fj.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
                                   "admin", "admin123", db="mysql")
MySQL.Connection(host="database-1.cez1pkekt7fj.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com", user="admin", port="3306", db="mysql")
```

It is however not recommended to store the data there (create your own database).